# Darboux's Theorem's Contrapositive Case

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Either find a differentiable function $g: \mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ such that $g \prime(0)=0$ and $g\prime(x)≥1$ if $x≠0$, or show that it is impossible to fulfill the condition.

My proof is as follows:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider the closed interval $[0, \epsilon]$.

Let us take $\delta$ such that $g \prime(0) = 0 < \delta < 1 \leq g \prime (\epsilon)$. Then, we find that $\nexists x \in (0, \epsilon)$ such that $g \prime (x) = \delta$ because $\forall x \in (0,\epsilon]$, $g \prime(x) \geq 1$. Using Darboux's theorem and the contrapositive case, $g$ is not differentiable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: g not differentiable at $\Bbb R,$ not only $[0,1]$.Your proof is correct and smart.

Comment: Side note: The derivative in TeX is `g^\prime(x)` or simply `g'(x)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use Darboux's theorem then you can simplify the argument by stating that $g'(0) = 0$ and $g'(1) \ge 1$, so that $g'$ must take the value $1/2$ somewhere, which it doesn't.

But you can show the impossibility to fulfill the condition also directly: For every $x > 0$ is
$$
 \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = g'(\xi) \ge 1
$$
for some $\xi \in (0, x)$, according to the mean value theorem. It follows that
$$
 g'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} \ge 1
$$
in contradiction to the assumption that $g'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. So, in the second explanation, we show that $g \prime (x)$ does not converge to 0 as required because $g \prime (\xi) \geq 0$? Also, your first explanation is just a specific case of my solution; so, my solution is perfectly okay as it is?

Comment: @throwawayAccountForRandomStuff: $g'(\xi) \ge 1$ shows that the limit must also be $\ge 1$, so it cannot be zero. Your proof is fine, but considering $\delta=1/2$ is sufficient to get a contradiction.